# How to find IP of a webserver in local network in Android using Java?

Tags: java, android, network-programming, esp32, lan

###### The context:

The webserver is running on a ESP32.
The Android app is being written in Java.
The Android phone & ESP32 are in same local network.
The minimum Android version is Lollipop (5.0).

---

###### The problem:

To find the IP (IPv4) of a webserver in local network in order to make further communication by making Http requests (GET & POST) to the webserver. Cannot use static IP & hence need to find the dynamically assigned IP.

###### The approach:

###### 1. The mDNS:

ESP32 supports mDNS but on Android, it is only supported from version 12. So, mDNS is being used from Android 12 & above without any problem.

###### 2. The looping:

Because mDNS cannot be used on Android below 12, current approach is to get the local IP (Ipv4) of the phone which will be w.x.y.z & then loop over the range w.x.y.0 to w.x.y.255, making a Http request (timeout set to 500ms for each request) to each IP to check if the IP is desired one by comparing the response. This will take forever so; multi-threading is being used which significantly reduces the time but still it is too much (in seconds).

---

###### The requirement:

A reliable & faster solution for the problem than the 2nd approach for Android below 12. The solution should work even if the local network is formed via a router or via hotspot of the same Android phone or via hotspot of some different phone.

Thanks in advance.

PS: Cannot implement DNS server or anything like so as the ESP32 is being used in a consumer product & as per the consumer POV, the data should be available from ESP32's webserver in the Android app without any user setup or configuration. Actual solution code is not a requirement (it would be great if you provide one) but a logic or general approach on how to solve this will also be appreciated.

Comment: A simple workaround that should work on many networks would be sending a special UDP packet to the local broadcast address of the network. On the ESP having the matching UDP port open and listening for that special UDP packet and it it is received send a response back to the sender. In the app you could listen for the response and once you get it the packet sender IP is the IP you are searching.

Comment: Thanks @Robert for your time. After posting the question, I was also researching for the solution & I also found about the UDP & it is working fine. I'll post the code so anyone in future will get the help.

Comment: `then loop over the range w.x.y.0 to w.x.y.255,` Did such before and always the server was found within seconds. Do ip's around client ip first. Use a Socket. You dont need http protocol.

Comment: Hi @blackapps, can you tell how much seconds it was taking approximately and how much timeout did you set to socket?

Answer (score 0):

After much research, I also came up with the UDP just as mentioned by @Robert in the comment & it works fine. Here is the code for anyone in need.

Android (Java)

```java
byte[] buffer = new byte[BYTE_SIZE];
try (DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(PORT)) {
    socket.setSoTimeout(5000);
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
    socket.receive(packet);
    String receivedIP = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
    // Rest of the code here to check if 'receivedIP' is desired one or not.
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

ESP32 code

```
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
// Other includes
WiFiUDP udp;
void setup() {
  // After connecting to LAN
  udp.begin(PORT);
}
void loop() {
  udp.beginPacket("255.255.255.255", PORT);
  udp.print(WiFi.localIP());
  udp.endPacket();
  // Rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Note that this solution creates a lot of (unnecessary) Wifi traffic as it will continuously send UDP packets to the Wifi network. This can reduce the battery of the device itself and all connected devices that run on battery. It would be better to only listen for UDP in the ESP and then send back a response if a special UDP packet is received via broadcast from the Android app.

Comment: is listening at ESP32 side for incoming packet a blocking procedure? if not you can post the code as your answer. asking because we're already utilizing both the cores and don't want to block any of them.

Comment: I never developed on ESP with UDP, but I would try to listen non-blocking (asynchronous). It seems like there are libraries that can do this: https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncUDP (just as en example, never used it).

Comment: I'll give it a try. It would be great if it works as it will overcome the problems in current answer like battery consumption, and like so.